# Change Sheet Direction with OpenExcel

Tags: c#, excel

I use this [OpenXML spreadsheet library](http://openexcel.codeplex.com/) to create excel document in my code.
The project does not have any documentation.

I want to change sheet direction from **left to right** to **right to left**.
Is that possible?

Comment: I have no experiences with OpenXML, is it related to [`EPPlus`](http://epplus.codeplex.com/releases/view/42439) since there's also an `OfficeOpenXml` namespace? Then i could show you an example.

Comment: **OpenExcel.OfficeOpenXml** this is the namespace

Comment: Of course it is. But since the names are equal i've wondered whether or not both projects are related/use the same engine.

Comment: I put link in my question for that matter

Answer (score 0):

You can use SheetView.RightToLeft property

```
SheetViews sheetViews1 = new SheetViews();  
SheetView sheetView1 = new SheetView()
{
     WorkbookViewId = (UInt32Value)0U, 
     RightToLeft = true
};  
sheetViews1.Append(sheetView1); 

worksheet.Append(sheetViews1);
```